# Cannot select partition in diskpart

Tags: partitioning, diskpart

I am trying to delete the partition on a USB flash drive (trying to format it using Windows 10 is unsuccessful). Using `diskpart` I get the following output:

```
DISKPART> list disk

  Disk ###  Status         Size     Free     Dyn  Gpt
  --------  -------------  -------  -------  ---  ---
  Disk 0    Online          232 GB      0 B
  Disk 1    Online           14 GB      0 B

DISKPART> select disk 1

Disk 1 is now the selected disk.

DISKPART> list partition

  Partition ###  Type              Size     Offset
  -------------  ----------------  -------  -------
* Partition 1    Primary             14 GB      0 B

DISKPART> select partition 1

There is no partition selected.

DISKPART> clean

DiskPart succeeded in cleaning the disk.

DISKPART> list partition

  Partition ###  Type              Size     Offset
  -------------  ----------------  -------  -------
* Partition 1    Primary             14 GB      0 B

DISKPART> delete partition

There are no partitions selected.
Please select a partition, and try again.

DISKPART> list volume

  Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info
  ----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
  Volume 0     F                       DVD-ROM         0 B  No Media
  Volume 1         System-rese  NTFS   Partition    100 MB  Healthy    System
  Volume 2     C                NTFS   Partition    169 GB  Healthy    Boot
  Volume 3     D   Volume       NTFS   Partition     62 GB  Healthy    Pagefile
  Volume 4                      NTFS   Partition    487 MB  Healthy    Hidden
* Volume 5     E                RAW    Removable     14 GB  Healthy
```

What is wrong? Is there anything else that's worth trying or is the hardware definitely broken?

Comment: @Walmart: That yields identical results as `select partition 1` and `delete partition`.

Comment: I didn't realize this was a USB and I read fast. I though you listed the part but forgot to sel it before the del command. I thought that's what I saw but I left as a quick comment only though to try to help quickly. . . I was wrong apparently but tried.

Comment: Same problem here, Windows 10 and SD card

Comment: Windows might try to force one partion per USB pendrive. Not sure why, but I remember running into clallenges like that quite often in the past. though multiple partition would likely require a partition table and offset-0 seems to tell me there is none

Comment: Try zapping LBA 0, https://superuser.com/a/1760400/705502

Answer (score 0):

I did this and it worked for me:

First select the proper disc. Next type in `disk clear readonly`

Next run the clean command.