# USB write-protect hardware/firmware based or not

Tags: linux, windows, usb, usb-flash-drive

I've got one old brandless giveaway USB flash pendrive, but *two disks* show up on the running systems instead. One of them is writable but the other is *readonly* even if there isn't physical write-protect switch visible outside.

*On Windows:*

```
WIN-R: diskpart

DISKPART> list disk
...
disk 1 online ...
disk 2 online ...

DISKPART> list volume
...
volume 2 normal ...
volume 3 normal ...

DISKPART> select disk 1
DISKPART> attributes disk
readonly status: no
readonly: no

DISKPART> select disk 2
DISKPART> list partition
partition 1 ...
DISKPART> attributes disk
readonly status: yes
readonly: yes
DISKPART> attributes disk clear readonly
DISKPART> attributes disk
readonly status: yes
readonly: no

DISKPART> select partition 1
DISKPART> format
error: write protection
```

*On Linux:*

```
$ sudo parted -l    
...
Model: Generic Flash Disk
Disk /dev/sdb ...
Warning: Unable to open /dev/sdc read-write (Read-only file system). /dev/sdc has been opened read-only.
Model: Generic Flash Disk
Disk /dev/sdc ...

$ sudo parted /dev/sdc
Warning: Unable to open /dev/sdc read-write (Read-only file system). /dev/sdc has been opened read-only.

(parted) print
number 1 ...

(parted) rm 1
error: not permitted to write
```

I've googled around and found this [article](https://www.getusb.info/what-replaces-write-protect-switch-on-usb-flash-drive/) on *internal hardware/firmware* based USB write-protect. How to verify if it is the case as mentioned by the article? Otherwise, how to remove this sort of USB write-protect?

I've also tried to *zero sector 0* with *diskpart* on Windows as commented *@JoepvanSteen*, but the *readonly* status remains.

```
DISKPART> clean
DISKPART> attributes disk
readyonly status: yes
readonly: no
DISKPART> clean
error: device i/o
```

Additionally, using *Disk Management* tool on Windows shows that the volume for *disk 2* has functional *FAT* filesystem, but all the writable options in the sub-menu popup from this volume become grayed out.

*As a side note,* I firstly posted this problem on *stackoverflow* and was hoping some firmware devs to give diagnosis hints, but the mod considered it off-topic. It's worthless in terms of economic value to solve this problem but valuable to learn and sort out the underlying during the course of investigation.

Comment: Does it matter if two show up, as long as you can write to one of them.

Comment: The two disks shown up aren't  physically same. Let's say the pendrive has 100 sectors, disk 1 is from 1 to 50, disk 2 from 51 to 100.

Comment: Can't you just zero sector 0 and create a new partition? See https://superuser.com/a/1760400/705502

Comment: @JoepvanSteen obviously this isn't due to partitioning

Comment: @JoepvanSteen, I did zero sector 0 on Windows without success.

Comment: What does no success mean exactly? Sector is not zeroed?

Comment: device i/o sounds like a defective device not worth anyone's time.

Comment: @JoepvanSteen, Doing *zero sector 0* was successful at the first time and all the existing files in disk 2 were corrupted as expected, but disk 2's  *readonly* status remains. Trying *zero sector 0* again failed with *device i/o* error.

Comment: Then it sounds *as if* at firmware level the UFD is configured to present itself as 2 physical drives (would be first time for me to see this). If then drv2 is configured read-only at firmware level there's not a lot you can do. What does it look like in DiskManagement? Can you add screenshot to OP?

Comment: @JoepvanSteen, *disk 1* always works flawlessly. All the contents in *disk 2* could be accessed readonly before *zero sector 0*. Unsure if the device was defective.

Comment: @JoepvanSteen, *disk 2* has been formatted with *FAT* filesystem on *Disk Management*  tool and remains readonly.

Comment: For me two indicators point to either firmware malfunction or misconfiguration. 1) *zero sector 0* worked at the first time, which meant *disk 2* was partially writable, but failure to *zero* again with *device i/o* error meant the firmware refused to accept further write operation. 2) clearing *readonly* led to inconsistent results - *readonly: NO* but *readonly status: YES*.

Comment: You can try if ChipGenius points to an MPtool you can use to configure the firmware.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going on with the investigation and approaching the root cause via standard Linux tools as follows.

Firstly, the USB device claims *disk 2* write-protect when it's plugged into the running host system, and the host follows the claim thus disables writable operations.

```
$ dmesg
New USB device found, idVendor=...., idProduct=....
[sdb] Write Protect is off
[sdc] Write Protect is on
```

Secondly, let the host believe in *disk 2* writable via [USB quirk mode](https://askubuntu.com/a/1088434), then the host can send the write request on *disk 2* to the device, but the device refuses to write on *disk 2* and responds [sense key data protect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_Code_Qualifier) to the host, so the *readonly* remains intact.

```
$ dmesg
[sdc] Assuming Write Enabled
[sdc] Write ...
[sdc] Sense Key : Data Protect
```

Finally, the USB drive controller is listed with a reputable vendor via *lsusb* command, and it can have imposed *readonly* status on *disk 2* indeed thus avoid unlocking effectively. On the other hand, the controller/firmware has somehow malfunctioned due to allowing *zero sector 0* initially, thus ruined the partition even if the data  content remains write-protect.

Comment: "the controller/firmware has somehow malfunctioned due to allowing zero sector 0 initially" .. probably just the last straw. If it's firmware lvl, which I think it is, it must be addressed that that level, see my chipgenius comment ^^^. It's very well possible firmware issues are a result of shitty NAND in which case this is all wasted effort.